# How can I correct a NullReferenceException in the following code?

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-4.5, nullreferenceexception

I'm new to programming and this may be a simple issue but I can't seem to figure it out. I have the following 2 classes in my program:

```
public class TrackingObject
{
public int OrderId { get; set; }
public int ProjectCount { get; set; }
public IList<ProjectInfo> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectInfo
{
public int ProjectId { get; set; }
public string ProjectType { get; set; }
public int ImageCount { get; set; }
}
```

For testing I created a console application and used the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TrackingObject oTracking = new TrackingObject();
    ProjectInfo pInfo = new ProjectInfo();

    oTracking.OrderId = 1;
    oTracking.ProjectCount = 1;
    pInfo.ProjectId = 1;
    pInfo.ProjectType = "CANVAS";
    pInfo.ImageCount = 1;
    oTracking.Projects.Add(pInfo);

    Console.WriteLine(oTracking.Projects.Count);
    Console.ReadLine();     
}
```

When I run the application it throws a NullReferenceException was unhandled on the following line:

```
    oTracking.Projects.Add(pInfo);
```

I understand enough to know that the exception is because oTracking.Projects is NULL. What is the correct way to accomplish what I am attempting? Any guidance will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `oTracking.Projects = new List<ProjectInfo>()` before adding items to it.

Comment: Do this in the constructor for TrackingObject

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't believe I missed something so basic. I'd vote you up if my rep was high enough.

Answer (score 2):

Combination of I4V's answer and first comment on that answer:

```cs
public class TrackingObject
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectCount { get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectInfo> Projects { get; set; }

    public TrackingObject() {
        this.Projects = new List<ProjectInfo>();
    }

    //This constructor optional, but since you're using an IList, may as well
    //let the user pass in an IList of a different type if they chose
    public TrackingObject(IList<ProjectInfo> defaultList) {
        this.Projects = defaultList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the object if `null`, if it is assign a new instance:

```
if (oTracking.Projects == null) {
  oTracking.Projects = new List<ProjectInfo>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Projects` needs to be initialized:

```
 oTracking.Projects = new List<ProjectInfo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
TrackingObject oTracking = new TrackingObject();
ProjectInfo pInfo = new ProjectInfo();

oTracking.OrderId = 1;
oTracking.ProjectCount = 1;
pInfo.ProjectId = 1;
pInfo.ProjectType = "CANVAS";
pInfo.ImageCount = 1;
oTracking.Projects = new List<ProjectInfo>();
oTracking.Projects.Add(pInfo);

Console.WriteLine(oTracking.Projects.Count);
Console.ReadLine();     
}
```